# ¿UTF encode o decode a un array?

Tags: php, array, utf-8

Estoy realizando un formulario donde tengo que mostrar una encuesta que está ya alojada en la BD. Tengo el problema de que toma caracteres raros...

> "Sr./Sra.CASER MIRO ROTUE �El t�cnico le brindo informaci�n del manejo de los equipos instalados?"

¿Cómo puedo hacer para ello? Ya probé con UTF antes del row y nada... Aquí les dejo el código que tengo.

```
$sql3="SELECT * FROM tbl_consumo_final INNER JOIN tbl_visitas ON tbl_consumo_final.PRIMARIA_VISITAS=tbl_visitas.PRIMARIA INNER JOIN tbl_encuesta ON tbl_consumo_final.NUM_CONSUMO=tbl_encuesta.NUM_CONSUMO WHERE tbl_visitas.OT=".$ot."";

            echo "<table id='tablatres'>

                        <thead>
                             <tr>
                                <td colspan='' rowspan='' headers=''> <h3>Preguntas</h3> </td>
                                <td colspan='' rowspan='' headers=''> <h3>Respuestas</h3> </td>
                            </tr>
                         </thead>";

        if($resultado3=$mysqli->query($sql3)) {

            while ($row = $resultado3->fetch_assoc()) {

                echo "<tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>$row[PREG_ENCUESTA]</td>
                                <td colspan='' rowspan='' headers=''> $row[RESP_ENCUESTA]</td>
                            </tr>";


            }

             echo "  </tbody>
               </table>";

               $resultado3->free();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Antes de irme directamente a la Base de Datos, buscaría la causa del error en un orden de prioridad, en el que el último serían precisamente los datos.

**Posibles causas del problema:**

1. Que el **documento HTML no tenga el [charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/meta) establecido a utf-8**, lo cual se hace con una etiqueta meta en el header:

   `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
2. **Que PHP no tenga el [charset](http://php.net/manual/es/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) establecido a utf-8.** Si es una página web en hosting compartido, a veces el chartset se disloca, cuando cambiamos de versión de PHP o cuando hay actualizaciones en el servidor, o cuando borramos el archivo .htaccess (lo digo por experiencia).
3. ¡Ahora sí! Si la causa no es ni 1 ni 2 entonces, el problema estaría en la base de datos. **¡Pero no ataques a los datos tan rápido!** Primero [verifica que estás dando un charset correcto cuando haces tu conexión](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php). Si es así, entonces sí, verifica el charset de la base de datos y de esa columna en específico. Si no es utf-8, se puede cambiar el charset de toda la base de datos, de toda la tabla, o de una columna en específico. Por supuesto, antes de hacer cambios de este tipo conviene hacer una copia de seguridad de la base de datos... nunca se sabe, algo puede salir mal. Para cambiar el charset, ver las [indicaciones de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html), bueno, imagino que es el sistema que utilizas.

   Aunque si antes funcionaba y ahora no, es posible que la causa no sea la base de datos, sino lo indicado en 1 o en 2.

Comment: +1, aunque yo también sugeriría usar [`htmlentities`](http://fr.php.net/htmlentities) antes de ir la la `DB`

Answer (score 0):

Según más te convenga realiza alguna de las siguientes sugerencias:

**Convertir en consulta**

En tu `$sql3="SELECT * FROM tbl_consumo_final INNER JOIN tbl_visitas ON ..."` colocar los campo y usar conversión con `CONVERT(column2 USING utf8)`; por lo que veo el dato es `$row[RESP_ENCUESTA]` por tanto sería `$sql3="SELECT  CONVERT(RESP_ENCUESTAUSING utf8) RESP_ENCUESTA, [los demas campos] FROM tbl_consumo_final INNER JOIN tbl_visitas ON ..."`

**Convertir al obtener el dato**

En la parte de tu codigo:

```
echo "<tr>
         <td>".utf8_encode($row["PREG_ENCUESTA"])."</td>
         <td colspan='' rowspan='' headers=''>".utf8_encode($row[RESP_ENCUESTA])."</td>
      </tr>";
```

El `TBODY` que colocas dentro del while no va; debe ser fuera del while antes de la iteracción; el while solo debe contener la formación de los `TR` y `TD` según corresponda.

**Convertir los datos en cada tabla**

De seguro no será el único dato donde te ocurrira lo de los símbolos; previo respaldo de la base de datos (y la información) hacer

```
UPDATE [TABLA] SET [CAMPO1]=CONVERT(CAMPO1 USING utf8), [CAMPO2]=CONVERT(CAMPO2 USING utf8)...[CAMPOn]=CONVERT(CAMPOn USING utf8)
```

para cada tabla; esto implica que la información en lo subsecuente será guardada en formato UTF8 (por los sistemas que alimentan esos datos) y ya no será necesario ninguna conversión (como las indicadas anteriormente) y el dato se obtiene para mostrarse directamente (es decir no moverias a tu codigo nada, solo sería actualizar los datos en las tablas).

Answer (score 0):

Claro esta que deberías trabajar en tu base datos con UTF8 para evitar estos problemas, de igual forma cuando hagas un insert indicar que la acción tambien sea UTF8.
Para dar solución al problema actual solo agrega:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_consumo_final";
```

Con esto, al momento que se ejecute tu consulta deberá  tratar tu *charset* como UTF8.

Para mayor información te agrega una liga de la documentación [oficial PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php)