# Visualización incorrecta de caracteres especiales

Tags: html5

¿Porqué no se muestran correctamente los caracteres especiales en [ésta página](http://www.xepelin.com/) ? 
He notado que contiene el atributo `<meta charset="utf-8">` pero aún así se muestran incorrectos.

Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues a esta pregunta el html que estas trabajando

Comment: utiliza esto, `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Mira esta respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/58922/29967 Ponle el meta completo y si no funciona, comprueba lo que se dice en 2 y en 3.

Answer (score 0):

Da un vistazo al origen de los datos; vocales acentuadas, la **ñ** entre otros en lugar de esas debes ver dos caracteres (salvo aquellos que no son visibles; pero estaran 2 juntos) si por ejemplo para **Más Información Próximamente** en vez de ver **MÃ¡s InformaciÃ³n PrÃ³ximamente** hay algo distinto (en vez de 2 caracteres para la **a** acentuada vez hay 4) tu información (para este caso *Más Información Próximamente*) fue aplicada dos veces la conversión a `utf8`.

Answer (score 0):

Los caracteres especiales en tu pagina se muestran perfectamente bien, lo que pasa es que tienes los caracteres especiales equivocados en las partes donde quieras. Probablemente eso pasó leyendo datos en utf-8, en el proximo paso interprentandolos como ISO-8859, y luego presentándolos como una pagina configurado como utf-8.

Si generas la página con php por ejemplo, asegúrate que tienes la siguiente configuración en tu php.ini:

```
default_charset = "utf-8"
mbstring.internal_encoding=utf-8
mbstring.http_output=UTF-8
mbstring.encoding_translation=On
mbstring.func_overload=6
```